# Javascript passing parameters to on('play') eventHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created an eventHandler for a html5 video on play element and bound it like this videoElement.on('play', eventHandler), but i can't seem to pass parameters. I tried passing it using on. I've tried to add .bind after .on(). Then i tried IIFEs and nothing seems to work. i can't seem to ever find my parameters in my console.

Been looking for awhile any help would be greatly appreciated ! Seems i still have to learn allot about jQuery.

The comments are some of what i tried.
JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4ghfdodg/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parameters = "someString";
    $("video").on('play', logModal);
});

function logModal(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

//$("video").on('play', parameters, logModal);
//$("video").on('play', logModal).bind(parameters);
//$("video").on('play', logModal).bind('data', parameters);
```

Comment: Do you get other output, if you would log in in the function? In other words, can you verify if the even handler gets called in the first place?

Comment: What do you want to add as parameter ? Maybe there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://api.jquery.com/on/ (Passing data to the handler)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //parameters have to be an object, not a string
  var parameters = {
    p: "someString"
  };
  $("video").on('play', parameters, logModal);
});

function logModal(e) {
  alert(e.data.p);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="360" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a function that can pass the event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parameters = "someString";
    $("video").on('play', function(e){ logModal(e, parameters); }); // <-- function
});

function logModal(e, parameters ) { console.log(e + '\n' + parameters); }
```

Edit: I noticed you tried to bind an event listener, this is how you can bind a context to an event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // use your parameters but as an object
    var parameters = {
        val : 'someString',
        num : 46
    };

    // bind the callback to your object
    $("video").on('play', function(e){
        logModal(e, this.val);
    }.bind(parameters)); 

});

function logModal(e, val){ 
    console.log(e + '\n' + val); 
}
```